# Numbers greater than $1000$ can be formed from the digits $1,1,2,2,3$

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many numbers greater than $1000$ can be formed from the digits $1,1,2,2,3$.

Please suggest the **shorter** way to solve this question.

Comment: Well, at least you said 'Please'. Now please show us what you've tried before asking us to solve your homework questions.

Answer (score 4):

*Four digit numbers*

Permutations of $1122, 1123$ and $1223$ = $\dfrac{4!}{2!2!} + 2\cdot\dfrac{4!}{2!} = 30$

*Five digit numbers*

$\dfrac{5!}{2!2!} = 30$

Adding up, answer = $60$

Answer (score 0):

There can be five digit numbers as well, so you need to break into cases:
(1) Four-digit case: as listed in S.Panja's solution.
(2) Five-digit case: Permuting 5 numbers with two repetition, so $5!\over2!2!$.

Comment: S.Panja-1729 did not list all of the four-digit numbers.